# Show content in separate page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, scroller

I am new to wordpress and I want to create Vertical news scroller plugin.In that I need to make the news headlines clickable and when clicked it should be displayed in another page with the option for user to login and add comments.How to do this?

Comment: When create new links, you should be able to select "Open in new window" check mark so the link will open in new window.  + the page there may ask for login info if user is not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a News theme or use any theme for that matter because you can create News posts, and when you click on the post, it will take you to the main post to read the article.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I need to create a news scroller plugin to be used in any themes.

Comment: So it will animate your news posts? There's a lot of plugins for this. Or create your own plugin using filters and hooks. Read more about this here http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API

Answer (score 0):

Make Every `News` as anchor (click able) like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">View Details</a>
```

This will redirect you to the `DETAIL` page of the respective news i.e: `single.php`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.when I give the above code it shows ?p=3 and shows not found.

Comment: Can you provide link of your source code? here `p=3` refers to the post ID of the news 3.